# Send Feature Attributes Along with Geometries to Difference Operation of Geometry Service

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, geometry-service

I've large number of data(geometries and attributes). I've to find their difference with other geometry, and after difference is calculated I've to assign attributes to those geometries. Example

```
Attribute-A  Geometry-A 
Attribute-B  Geometry-B
Attribute-C  Geometry-C
```

and

```
SubtractorGeometry-B
```

[Note: Geometry-B will get subtracted by SubtractorGeometry-B]

Expected Result:

```
Attribute-A  Geometry-A 
Attribute-C  Geometry-C
```

The problem I'm facing is that difference operation only accepts geometries and not attributes. When difference returns result, I don't know which attribute do I've to assign to which geometry.

One workaround is to send each geometry separately and assign attributes when it returns result, but for large data that's impractical  as for 1000 records their will be 1000 service calls.

Can anyone please suggest any solution?